# ubuntu 22.04 Remote desktop showing black screen

Tags: screen, remote-desktop, remote-access, rdp

I'm using the built-in remote desktop on ubuntu 22.04, and I can connect without issue, however, I do not get any video. The keyboard and mouse work but there is only a black screen.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution, switch from wayland to xorg on login screen